# REGEXP_REPLACE for alpha to NULL

Tags: regex, postgresql, replace, postgresql-13

While converting Oracle to Postgresql I came to know the following Oracle query need to be converted in Postgres.

Oracle Query: Find pattern and replace with `null`

```
select regexp_replace('1', '[^0-9]', null) from dual;
select regexp_replace('a', '[^0-9]', null) from dual;
select regexp_replace('1a1', '[^0-9]', null) from dual;
```

**My try**:

As per the [postgres document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html) we need to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` with `[[:alpha:]]` pattern.

But the statement is replacing with   empty string if match found. I'm looking for `null` instead.

PostgreSQL Query:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('1','[[:alpha:]]','','g') --Correct
select REGEXP_REPLACE('a','[[:alpha:]]','','g') --Wrong: output should be NULL
select REGEXP_REPLACE('1a1','[[:alpha:]]','','g') --Correct
select REGEXP_REPLACE(' ','[[:alpha:]]','','g') --Wrong: output should be NULL
```

Definitely we can use `case` statement like following but I want the solution in single line without using `case` condition.

```
SELECT case when REGEXP_REPLACE('1a','[[:alpha:]]','','g') = '' 
       then 
           null 
       else 
           REGEXP_REPLACE('1a','[[:alpha:]]','','g') 
       end;
```

Comment: In Postgres (and essentially every other DBMS) an empty string (`''`)  is something different than a `null` value. So if you replace all characters in a string, the result is an empty string, not a null value. If you want to treat an empty string as null use `nullif(..., '')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I need to convert this column into `::bigint` post `regexp`.

Comment: Then use `nullif()`

Comment: Something like this? select NULLIF(REGEXP_REPLACE('a','[[:alpha:]]','','g'), '')::BIGINT;